# How to store dynamically created textbox values into sql server database table in WPF

Tags: c#, sql-server

How to store dynamically created textbox values into a SQL Server database table in WPF? I have created textboxes and check boxes dynamically like this,

```
private void addItembutton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chk_add = new CheckBox();
    chk_add.MaxWidth = 100;

    TextBox tb_add = new TextBox();
    tb_add.Width = 200;
    tb_add.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;

    chk_add.Content = tb_add;

    wrapPanel1.Children.Add(chk_add);

    chk_add.Margin = new Thickness(10, lastheight, 0, 0);
 }
```

Now I want to store these texboxes values into database table and retrieve them into a datagrid?

Comment: You should look into MVVM and DataTemplates

Answer (score 0):

you need to have reference to those dinamically created textboxes. You may want to store them in a List of TextBox. So that in the end you can iterate trhough the list to get textboxes value, and store them into database. This is the code to clarify what i mean:

```
List<TextBox> TextBoxes = new List<TextBox>();

private void addItembutton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ...

    TextBox tb_add = new TextBox();
    tb_add.Width = 200;
    tb_add.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
    TextBoxes.Add(tb_add);

    ...
}

private void SaveToDatabase()
{
    foreach(TextBox tb in TextBoxes)
    {
        var text = tb.Text;
        //save text to database
    }
}
```